# Increase Swap partion size

Tags: partitioning

My newly installed Ubuntu 15.10 can not enter hibernation.

The PC has 4gb ram, and the swap partion is 4 GB (but when I check the real size of the `/linux-swap` partion, I found out it is only 3.73 GB!), so is it the reason that the Ubuntu can not enter hibernation?

How big should the swap partition be so that the system can enter hibernation? Or is there other way to do the same trick? How difficult is to enlarge the swap partition size?

The following shows partitions of my hard drive. Unfortunately there is no unallocated partition around the `/swap` partition. (showed between `sda3` (which is `/` partion) and `sda2` (which is a windows extended NTFS partition, almost empty). Is there a way to cut several GB from the neighbor partitions to add to the swap partition? Thank you.

Here is a screenshot:

[image: Here's a Screenshot.]

Comment: Don't know why the image didn't show.

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase swap in such way https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-14-04 . It is pretty easy and safely. Then test hibernate or etc.  Maybe reason of your problem not in swap size.

Comment: Thank you ipeacocks, for the info, looks very in detail and good article. I am thinking, I doubt, as you implied too, that the hibernation thing has something to do with the size of my swap partition, cause it has already 4 gb. I will test it anyway. Have a nice day.